# Lazy load util function in React

Tags: reactjs, react-lazy-load, webpack-module-federation

I want to run a JS function from a module that loaded asynchronously (that exposed by module federation)
and to use the return value in a React component.

For example, setting the visibility of some element by the value of a function that returns a boolean value.

All of the examples that I found, explain how to lazy load React components

Thanks!
Shlomi

Comment: Show what has already been done. lazy load only for react components, not for funcions

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to run the function once when the component first loads, you can simply do so using, for example a `useEffect()` hook and then set some state. For example

```
function MyComponent(){
   const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState()
   useEffect( () => {
     import('someRemote/module').then( module => {
        const valueFromFunction = module.myFunction()
        setSomeValue(valueFromFunction)
     })
   })
   return someValue != undefined ? <div>The value is {someValue}</div> : <></>
}
```